# Why does `git-svn` hang at `Found possible branch point:`

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, svn2git

Since a few days, my `git-svn` hangs at `Found possible branch point: .../trunk => .../branches/foo, 8809` when I do `git svn fetch`.

The clone acutally is at revision `163671` already.
My box had a freeze lately, so it might be that something got stuck during a `git svn fetch` when it froze and I had to reboot my Windows machine.

I tried to move `.git/svn/` out of the way and let `git svn` recover, but it just rebuilds `trunk` and some others and then hangs at the exact same position again.

Does anyone have any idea why it might hang there suddenly and how to recover besides of a fresh git svn clone which would need a week or so. I'd prefer if there would be another way.

Comment: Make sure you're using the very latest available version of Git. I had lots of problems with pre-2.5 `git-svn`.

Comment: @Will It is 2.8.1.windows.1

Comment: @Will, also 2.8.3 makes no difference

Comment: I've used Git + `git-svn` from Linux to work with 100K+ revision repo without issues. Did your original`git svn clone <url>` command actually finish and you're just trying to get the content that was most recently checked-in? Did you clone from the root of the repository? Also, I normally use `git svn rebase` to pull in the most recent changes from upstream, not `fetch`. Did you use the arguments to specify the paths to `branches`, `tags`, and `trunk` directories in the upstream during clone?

Comment: @ray Yes, I use this repo since years. Yes, I cloned from the root and I used `-s` for branches / tags layout. `git svn rebase` does nothing else than doing a `git svn fetch` and then a `git rebase`. I have a job that runs every 15 minutes and does a `git svn fetch` so that I don't have to wait for ages when I want to update or dcommit and so that I have all branch content locally. Actually I got past the hanging by using `-r` for `git svn fetch` and specifying a revision I know was fetched for all branches already and now it works normally again. Still curious why it hanged if happens again.

Comment: @Vampire, The only instances where I've noticed something doesn't quite behave as expected is if, for some reason, the process terminated abruptly (e.g. timeout fetching content, process killed, etc) and the state of the repository was messed up (changed content, but didn't actually create the local commit, so it looks "edited" on `git status`). In those rare cases, I've simply issued a `git reset --hard` and then `git svn rebase` my way to victory. I've never seen this issue. Did you get some error message on client or server or found something in the SVN repo that would allow reproducing it?

Comment: @ray There was no error message somewhere, just the hanging at the message as described above. As I wrote above the trigger could be a freeze of my box. But the hang was not a temporary thing, but it hanged for weeks every time I tried to run `git svn fetch` without the `--parent` parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Fresh clone should not be taking weeks. You can always do a shallow git-svn clone (see `-r` Option) to speed things up. Or if you have an acces to a **Linux** box - clone there and copy the repo to your windows workstation. Git-svn clone is notoriously slow in win.

Comment: A shallow clone is useless as it has no history and the slow part is our SVN server which is dead lame and last time it took about 1 week to import the ~160.000 revisions as far as I remember.

Comment: How much history do you need to wait that one week for the full clone?

Comment: I need all history. The history of a project is part of the project. Without you cannot annotate and look at how things changed. People that say that history of sourcecode is not important are plainly shortsighted.

Comment: Besides that, I want to know why it does not work and not only a work-around.

Comment: and fresh clone does not work as it dies of signal 11 :-(